# Converting American Date format to a Date Using a Formula

Tags: formula, date

I'm converting an American Date format string to a Date using the following Formula.

For example, this will convert a String like "9/25/2015" to an actual Date field that can be used in reports, list views, etc.

```
IF(LEN(LD__c)==8, 
DATE(VALUE(MID(LD__c, 5, 4)), VALUE(MID(LD__c, 3, 1)), VALUE(MID(LD__c, 1, 1))), 
IF(LEN(LD__c)==10, 
DATE(VALUE(MID(LD__c, 7, 4)), VALUE(MID(LD__c, 1, 2)), VALUE(MID(LD__c, 4, 2))), 
IF(FIND("/", LD__c)==2, 
DATE(VALUE(MID(LD__c, 6, 4)), VALUE(MID(LD__c, 1, 1)), VALUE(MID(LD__c, 3, 2))), 
DATE(VALUE(MID(LD__c, 6, 4)), VALUE(MID(LD__c, 1, 2)), VALUE(MID(LD__c, 4, 1))) 
)))
```

This is working great, but any suggestions on how to simplify it?

Comment: One long term option would be voting for [Enable Admins to Write Custom Formula Functions with Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrgfAAC). The DateValue function may help, but I believe it needs the string format to be "YYYY-MM-DD"